# MySQL: How to check "next item" recursively

Tags: mysql, recursion, join

Need to check "next_item_id" and if it matches "resource_item_id" keep selecting, but when reach a Null value or "next_item_id" could not be found in "resource_item_id" stop, only select connected series of items, for specific "resource_id", please check attached picture:

Sample of data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f1b91

[image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: wouldn't be a good solution to prepare two things:
process that handles all not null items and another process that handles null items? that would allow the process to constantly run on both sets without stopping OR quickly find broken records

Comment: The keyword is "Recursive Common Table Expressions" to create a view with select query, which resolves the levels and relationship between hierachal lines: see within documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: @Strawberry updated

Comment: That's progress.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the sqlfiddle to dbfiddle, as in the second one MySQL 8.0 is active with common table expressions. First I declare a view with the CTE:

```
CREATE VIEW v_resource_item_stop AS 
with recursive cte (`resource_id`, `resource_item_id`, `next_item_id`, 
                    `previous_item_id`, `created_at`, 
                    `updated_at`,`resource_stop_id`,resource_nlevel) as (
SELECT `resource_id`, `resource_item_id`, `next_item_id`, `previous_item_id`, 
                     `created_at`, `updated_at`,
                     resource_item_id AS resource_stop_id, 1 AS resource_nlevel 
FROM resource_items  WHERE next_item_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT r1.`resource_id`, r1.`resource_item_id`, r1.`next_item_id`, 
                      r1.`previous_item_id`, r1.`created_at`, r1.`updated_at`,
                      cte.resource_stop_id,cte.resource_nlevel+1 AS resource_nlevel
FROM resource_items r1 INNER JOIN cte ON r1.next_item_id = cte.resource_item_id
                      ) SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY resource_item_id;
```

And for the final result in start and stop I use the following query:

```
SELECT resource_item_id AS resource_start_id,resource_stop_id,resource_nlevel 
FROM v_resource_item_stop
WHERE CONCAT(resource_stop_id,'#',resource_nlevel) IN
(SELECT CONCAT(resource_stop_id,'#',MAX(resource_nlevel)) FROM v_resource_item_stop
GROUP BY resource_stop_id);
```

Hope that helps.
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `resource_items` (
  `resource_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `resource_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `next_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `previous_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE VIEW v_resource_item_stop AS 
with recursive cte (`resource_id`, `resource_item_id`, `next_item_id`, 
                    `previous_item_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`,`resource_stop_id`,resource_nlevel) as (
SELECT `resource_id`, `resource_item_id`, `next_item_id`, `previous_item_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`,
                     resource_item_id AS resource_stop_id, 1 AS resource_nlevel 
FROM resource_items
                      WHERE next_item_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT r1.`resource_id`, r1.`resource_item_id`, r1.`next_item_id`, r1.`previous_item_id`, 
                      r1.`created_at`, r1.`updated_at`,
                      cte.resource_stop_id,cte.resource_nlevel+1 AS resource_nlevel
FROM resource_items r1 INNER JOIN cte ON r1.next_item_id = cte.resource_item_id
                      ) SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY resource_item_id;

INSERT INTO `resource_items` (`resource_id`, `resource_item_id`, `next_item_id`, `previous_item_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1163, 2028, 2029, NULL, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2029, 2030, 2028, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2030, 2031, 2029, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2031, 2032, 2030, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2032, 2033, 2031, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2033, 2034, 2032, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2034, NULL, 2033, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2035, 2036, 2034, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2036, 2037, 2035, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2037, 2038, 2036, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2038, 2039, 2037, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2039, 2040, 2038, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2040, 2041, 2039, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2041, 2042, 2040, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06'),
(1163, 2042, NULL, 2041, '2017-10-20 09:57:06', '2017-10-20 09:57:06');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT resource_item_id AS resource_start_id,resource_stop_id,resource_nlevel FROM v_resource_item_stop
WHERE CONCAT(resource_stop_id,'#',resource_nlevel) IN
(SELECT CONCAT(resource_stop_id,'#',MAX(resource_nlevel)) FROM v_resource_item_stop
GROUP BY resource_stop_id);

| resource_start_id | resource_stop_id | resource_nlevel |
| ----------------- | ---------------- | --------------- |
| 2028              | 2034             | 7               |
| 2035              | 2042             | 8               |
```